# Rust - Reqwest can't make a request

Tags: rust, request, http-status-code-403, rust-cargo, reqwest

I've been trying for about 1 day to make a GET request in squarecloud domain (hosting services). To access their API to make some stuff in my applications.

I'm trying to make this request with reqwest lib, and it's returning me `Status Code: 403 (Forbidden)`.

I tested with Python, Insomnia and with Rust but with another lib called `ureq`. In all of them worked perfectly. Except reqwest.

Here's my .toml file

```
[package]
name = "request-rust-testing"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11.23", features = ["json"] }
futures = "0.3.30"
tokio = { version = "1.35.1", features = ["full"] }
```

And here's my main.rs file

```
use reqwest::{ self };

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut headers = reqwest::header::HeaderMap::new();

    headers.insert("authorization", "<authorization>".parse().unwrap());

    let response = client.get("https://api.squarecloud.app/v2/user")
        .headers(headers)
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", response);
}
```

403 Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class=\"no-js ie6 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class=\"no-js ie7 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class=\"no-js ie8 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"en-US\"> <!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\" />\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, nofollow\" />\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"cf_styles-css\" href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css\" />\n<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel=\"stylesheet\" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css\" /><![endif]-->\n<style>body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>\n\n\n<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->\n<script>\n  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {\n    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {\n      var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');\n      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';\n    })\n  }\n</script>\n<!--<![endif]-->\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div id=\"cf-wrapper\">\n    <div class=\"cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error\" id=\"cookie-alert\" data-translate=\"enable_cookies\">Please enable cookies.</div>\n    <div id=\"cf-error-details\" class=\"cf-error-details-wrapper\">\n      <div class=\"cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview\">\n        <h1 data-translate=\"block_headline\">Sorry, you have been blocked</h1>\n        <h2 class=\"cf-subheadline\"><span data-translate=\"unable_to_access\">You are unable to access</span> squarecloud.app</h2>\n      </div><!-- /.header -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-section cf-highlight\">\n        <div class=\"cf-wrapper\">\n          <div class=\"cf-screenshot-container cf-screenshot-full\">\n            \n              <span class=\"cf-no-screenshot error\"></span>\n            \n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-section cf-wrapper\">\n        <div class=\"cf-columns two\">\n          <div class=\"cf-column\">\n            <h2 data-translate=\"blocked_why_headline\">Why have I been blocked?</h2>\n\n            <p data-translate=\"blocked_why_detail\">This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.</p>\n          </div>\n\n          <div class=\"cf-column\">\n            <h2 data-translate=\"blocked_resolve_headline\">What can I do to resolve this?</h2>\n\n            <p data-translate=\"blocked_resolve_detail\">You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.</p>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.section -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300\">\n  <p class=\"text-13\">\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1\">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class=\"font-semibold\">849ad712797c1a9e</strong></span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-separator sm:hidden\">&bull;</span>\n    <span id=\"cf-footer-item-ip\" class=\"cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1\">\n      Your IP:\n      <button type=\"button\" id=\"cf-footer-ip-reveal\" class=\"cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn\">Click to reveal</button>\n      <span class=\"hidden\" id=\"cf-footer-ip\">177.200.130.247</span>\n      <span class=\"cf-footer-separator sm:hidden\">&bull;</span>\n    </span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1\"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" href=\"https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing\" id=\"brand_link\" target=\"_blank\">Cloudflare</a></span>\n    \n  </p>\n  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById(\"cf-footer-item-ip\"),c=a.getElementById(\"cf-footer-ip-reveal\");b&&\"classList\"in b&&(b.classList.remove(\"hidden\"),c.addEventListener(\"click\",function(){c.classList.add(\"hidden\");a.getElementById(\"cf-footer-ip\").classList.remove(\"hidden\")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\",d)})();</script>\n</div><!-- /.error-footer -->\n\n\n    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->\n  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->\n\n  <script>\n  window._cf_translation = {};\n  \n  \n</script>\n\n<script>(function(){var js = \"window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'849ad712797c1a9e',t:'MTcwNTk1ODQxOC4zMTgwMDA='};_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);\";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script><script defer src=\"https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/v84a3a4012de94ce1a686ba8c167c359c1696973893317\" integrity=\"sha512-euoFGowhlaLqXsPWQ48qSkBSCFs3DPRyiwVu3FjR96cMPx+Fr+gpWRhIafcHwqwCqWS42RZhIudOvEI+Ckf6MA==\" data-cf-beacon='{\"rayId\":\"849ad712797c1a9e\",\"b\":1,\"version\":\"2024.1.0\",\"token\":\"d141d4a970ea4f71959e0c44b59b0257\"}' crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\n</body>\n</html>
```

Code write in ureq that works:

```
fn main() {
    let url = "https://api.squarecloud.app/v2/user";
    let res = ureq::get(url)
    .set("authorization", "<authorization>")
    .call()
    .unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", res.into_string());
}
```

You can try making a request in `https://api.squarecloud.app/v2/service/statistics`. You don't need a token to access this one.

Comment: Can you 1. print out the body of the 403 response, and 2. show the ureq code that did work?

Comment: @drewtato sure. 1 sec, gonna rewrite ureq code.

Comment: The ureq and reqwest code examples are not hitting the same endpoint, so it's not meaningful to compare them. Show us the _working_ ureq code that is hitting the same exact endpoint as the reqwest code using the same headers.

Comment: That's not the body of the response. Call `text` to get the body.

Comment: I tested right now, same endpoint, passing the header. Worked in ureq. Ty for correcting me @cdhowie

Comment: Changed respose to text that returns to me. It's a html response. @drewtato

Comment: Okay, well the response indicates you've hit the Cloudflare captcha page, which can happen for a variety of reasons. Since it works from ureq, I would try setting a custom user agent in the reqwest one and seeing if that helps.

Comment: I was thinking if could be something about cloudflare. I added a custom user agent and it worked! Thank you! @drewtato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @drewtato. Solution is adding a custom User-Agent in the request.

```
use reqwest::{ self };

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut headers = reqwest::header::HeaderMap::new();

    headers.insert("authorization", "<authorization>".parse().unwrap());
    headers.insert("user-agent","CUSTOM_NAME/1.0".parse().unwrap());

    let response = client.get("https://api.squarecloud.app/v2/user")
        .headers(headers)
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", response);
}
```